# How do I merge two pandas dataframes with non overlapping rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following two data frames with odd and even rows and I need to merge them into a single dataframe with the same columns, but in order since they are odd and even:

```
In [88]: ax1.loc[:, :'dx1']
Out[88]: 
         what  dc1  dj1  dm1  dx1
1660920     2   14   10    5   11
1660922     4    6   15    1   12
1660924    11   15    7    1    0
1660926    13    6   13    2    1
1660928     8    5    9   15    8
1660930    15    7    7    2   14
1660932     7    8    9   14   15
1660934     7    0    8    0    9
1660936    10   13    3    3    5
1660938    12    6    9    4    5
1660940     4    8    1    7    1
1660942     0    4    1    9    5
1660944    14   14   11   15   15
1660946     2   12   13    3    7
1660948     7    5    0   12    8
1660950     7    0   15   10    0
1660952     7    0    7    7   15
1660954     3    4   12   12    3
1660956     4    7    7    3   11
1660958    10   14    1    6    9
1660960     0   10    9    7   11
1660962     8    8    3    9    1

In [89]: ax2.loc[:, :'dx1']
Out[89]: 
         what  dc1  dj1  dm1  dx1
1660921    11    0    7    4    8
1660923    12    0   14    9    0
1660925     0    0    4    8    2
1660927     1    0   10   11    5
1660929     8    0    5   12    3
1660931    14    0    6    0    3
1660933    15    0    0    1    7
1660935     9    0   14    8    6
1660937     5    0    2   14    2
1660939     5    0   15   15    2
1660941     1    0   13    9   11
1660943     5    0    1    5    9
1660945    15    0   15    5   11
1660947     7    0    9    1    7
1660949     8    0   10    5    6
1660951     0    0    7   15    2
1660953    15    0    8    7    8
1660955     3    0    4    8    4
1660957    11    0    8    0   12
1660959     9    0   13   15   10
1660961    11    0    1    3   15
1660963     1    0    1   11   11
```

I'm currently getting an error about the columns overlapping: ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified. But I just want to merge by index so that the rows are in order. I can reset the index's if needed but I need to keep them in order something like:

```
         what  dc1  dj1  dm1  dx1
1660920     2   14   10    5   11
1660921    11    0    7    4    8
1660922     4    6   15    1   12
1660923    12    0   14    9    0


etc.
```

I did search but only found column based merges, not in row for odd even indexes which keep the same column names.

Comment: Use: `pd.concat([ax1, ax2]).sort_index()`